# Tiktok monetization using vpn on educational content because tiktok monetization ks currently unavailable in pakistan. Is it halal or haram?

Tags: halal-haram, sharia

Tiktok monetization is currently not available in Pakistan but it is available in USA. By using vpn we can get access to tiktok monetization because it changes our location. Would it be halal or haram?